# How to list my Documents in Google Drive inside Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I have a bunch of pdf documents in Google drive and I want them listed as table with pdf thumbnail and name of pdf with link to the where it is in Google drive on my Google sites webpage. I want it to be automated so everytime I upload a file on Google drive it automatically appears on Google Sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites) ?

It could be a good start for you to develop your own application...

Comment: thanks for the link. btw that particular link is slightly outdated but still usefull.